# Replace internal state of Matrix object

Tags: ruby

Similar to `Array#pop()`, I want to create a destructive method that removes the last column of a matrix: `Matrix#hpop()` (h stands for horizontal).

How can I make this method destructive? There is no such method like `Matrix#replace()` that I could use to modify the internal state of the object.

```
  # Removes trailing columns from a Matrix.
  # @param number_of_columns [Integer] number of trailing columns to be removed
  # @return [Matrix] matrix
  # @raise [ErrDimensionMismatch] if Matrix does not have enough columns for operation
  def hpop(number_of_columns = 1)        
    Matrix.Raise ErrDimensionMismatch unless number_of_columns < self.column_count

    columns = []
    last_column_to_be_included = self.column_count - number_of_columns
    self.column_vectors.each_with_index do |column, index|
      break if index + 1 > last_column_to_be_included
      columns << column.to_a
    end

    Matrix.columns(columns) # should be destructive        
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can patch the Matrix class to drop a column...

```
class Matrix
  def drop_column
    @rows.each {|r| r.pop}
  end
end


my_matrix = Matrix.build(3,5) { 1 }
=> Matrix[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]] 

my_matrix.drop_column

p my_matrix
 => Matrix[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

or similarly to drop a row

```
class Matrix
  def drop_row
    @rows.pop
  end
end
```

EDIT

So in fact hpop would be...

```
def hpop(number_of_columns = 1)        
  Matrix.Raise ErrDimensionMismatch unless number_of_columns < column_count

  dropped_columns = []
  number_of_columns.times do
    dropped_column = []      
    @rows.each {|r| dropped_column << r.pop}
    dropped_columns << dropped_column
  end

  @column_count -= number_of_columns

  Matrix.columns(dropped_columns.reverse)
end
```

(code is taken from your own source, just added the `@column_count -= ...` line)

EDIT #2

And a vpop method would probably be...

```
class Matrix
  def vpop(number_of_rows = 1)
    Matrix.Raise ErrDimensionMismatch unless number_of_rows < @rows.size
    dropped_rows = []
    number_of_rows.times { dropped_rows.unshift @rows.pop }
    Matrix.columns(dropped_rows)
  end
end
```

Comment: Good one, Steve!  I'll have to look at the source for `Matrix`.

Comment: Thx. I implemented and took me a while to figure out why comparison tests failed. Example: `expect(Matrix[ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ].hpop).to eq Matrix[ [1,2], [4,5] ]` fails. Also, `Matrix[ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ].hpop.column_size` returns 3, it seems almost that the Matrix class is not designed for change.

Comment: Here's the entire code http://pastebin.com/bKbVgXrY with all tests http://pastebin.com/s5AYSNbb

Comment: Remember that `array.pop` returns the last element, removed from the array.  It doesn't return the array.   Similarly, `Matrix[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]].hpop` should return the removed column, not the new matrix, so your test is going to fail.  you probably need to do `test_matrix = Matrix[ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ] ; test_matrix.hpop ; expect(test_matrix).to eq  Matrix[ [1,2], [4,5] ]`

Comment: This failed. It's very strange, the objects look the same but they are not. Here's the output from my console: `m23c = Matrix[ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ]`, `m23c.hpop`, `puts m23c => Matrix[[1, 2], [4, 5]]` and then things start to get weird `m23c == Matrix[ [1,2], [4,5] ]
=> false` and `puts m23c.column_count => 3`

Comment: Ah, that's it!  `column_count` is an instance variable, attr_reader.  In your hpop method you will have to include `@column_count -= number_of_columns`   ... I'll edit my answer.

Comment: That worked, the comparison tests pass now. Do you have any ideas how I can implement `#vpop()` (popping rows). There's no `@columns` variable and I can't pop a column vector.